# Journal name not showing in reference (Natbib)

Tags: natbib

I'm using natbib to create the references but it's not showing all the information about the reference.

Here is my .bib:

```
@JOURNAL{OpticsCommunications,
author = "Ricci, L. and Weidemüller, M. and Esslinger, T. and Hemmerich, A. and Zimmermann, C. and Vuletic, V. and König, W. and Hänsch, T.W.",
title = "A compact grating-stabilized diode laser system for atomic physics",
journal = "Optics Communications",
year = "1995",
volume = "117",
pages ="541-549",}
```

This is the reference on the paper:
[image]

How do I get the journal name, volume and page number to show?

Comment: What are the options given to the `natbib` package ? What style do you use ?

Comment: \usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
and 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

Comment: off topic, but you probably want "`pages`" instead of "`number`".

Comment: Please provide a working example. Nobody knows which options you already use for your bibliography (e.g. `natbib`-options, `\bibliographystyle`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have marked your input as type `@journal`, but this is non-standard so will be treated as for `@misc`. You need to use `@article` (an article in a journal).